# Supplying registrar with dnssec related records

Tags: dnssec

I have a domain name under `.money`, which supports DNSSEC.

However, my registrar hasn't done DNSSEC with this TLD before and is asking me to supply the Key Tag, Algorithm Type, Digest Type and Digest -- and they will set them.

However, I am lost on how to obtain the right values from the TLD. Can I query them from the root server, from the `.money` NS servers, or is the registrar being lazy here and do they need to generate some keys here?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You should set your own keys etc. and let the TLD know respective `DS` records so that the delegation can be secure, not the other way around. Or am I totally misunderstanding the question?